# initialize to dynamically allocated char array from a struct

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize dynamically allocated char array to different types within a struct called term, which is a struct that holds parts of a polynomial, (coefficient, var, exponent). The function is a to_string function which returns the struct term as a string of form, "cx^e", or "c" if the term has an exponent of 0.

I believe I have the overall thought process correct for creating the string however I don't know if I'm initializing my `char *ptr` correctly.

Here's the related code:

The to_string function

```
char *term_to_string(const term_t *term)
{
  char *ptr;
  if (term->exponent == 0)
  {
    ptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(term->coefficient));
    memset(ptr, 'x', sizeof(term->coefficient));
    *ptr = term->coefficient;
  }
  else if (term->coefficient == 1)
  {
    ptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof (term->var) + sizeof (term->exponent) + sizeof (char));
    *ptr = term->var;
    *(ptr + 1) = '^';
    *(ptr + 2) = term->exponent;
  }
  else
  {
    ptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(term->coefficient) +
                          sizeof(term->var) +
                          sizeof(term->exponent) +
                          sizeof(char));
    *ptr = term->coefficient;
    *(ptr + 1) = term->var;
    *(ptr + 2) = '^';
    *(ptr + 3) = term->exponent;                      
  }


  return ptr;
}
```

The struct "term"

```
typedef struct term 
{
  int exponent, coefficient;
  char var;
} term_t;
```

Testing the to_string

```
term_t testterm1 = {1, 'x', 0};
term_t testterm2 = {2, 'x', 1};
term_t testterm3 = {3, 'x', 2};


printf("Testing term.c/h:\n");
printf("testterm1: %s\n", term_to_string(&testterm1));
printf("testterm2: %s\n", term_to_string(&testterm2));
printf("testterm3: %s\n", term_to_string(&testterm3));
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault error, and I know it has something to do with trying to initialize a NULL pointer. However, I'm confused as to:

1) What size I should allocate the pointer to? (I'm using `sizeof(term->coefficient)` right now in the first block of my if statement)

2) If I'm properly initializing my pointer? (I used `memset` in the first block of the if statement but I really don't think I'm using it right at all)

The expected outcome should be

```
x
2x
3x^2
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: `str` is uninitialized.

Comment: I removed ```str``` and just returned ptr but it still gives me the same error

Comment: This is all totally, irrecoverably wrong. Scrap it. Strings don't work this way. Use `snprintf` to format your term (and another call to `snprintf` to determine how much space you need to allocate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four problems :

- the string returned by `term_to_string` is not terminated by the character having the code 0, so each *printf* to write the result goes out of the allocated array with an undefined behavior
- the way you expect to insert the external representation of the integer value is wrong, for instance to do `*ptr = term->coefficient` just set one character having the code of `term->coefficient` casted (truncated) to a char
- the ways you compute the size of the allocated string are wrong, the size of external representation of an *int* is not given by *sizeof*
- your initializations of the struct are wrong, the second value ('x') is visibly the char but you initialize *coefficient* with it, you need to respect the order of the fields.

If `{3, 'x', 2};` has to produce `3x^2` that means the first field of the *struct* must be *coefficient* (rather than *exponent*), the second must be *var* (rather than *coefficient*) and the third must be *exponent* (rather than *var*). Or without changing the definition of the *struct* you have to modify the initialization order to have `term_t testterm3 = {2, 3, 'x'};`.

Also `{1, 'x', 0}`  cannot produce "x", it has to produce "1" or "0"

---

Without changing the definition of the *struct* and adding special cases you do not managed a proposal can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct term 
{
  int exponent, coefficient;
  char var;
} term_t;

int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);

char *term_to_string(const term_t *term)
{
  char *ptr;

  if ((term->exponent == 0) || (term->coefficient == 0))
  {
    ptr = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", term->coefficient) + 1); /* +1 for char \0 */
    sprintf(ptr, "%d", term->coefficient);
  }
  else if (term->coefficient == 1)
  {
    if (term->exponent == 1)
    {
      ptr = malloc(2);
      ptr[0] = term->var;
      ptr[1] = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
      ptr = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", term->exponent) + 3); /* +3 for var and ^ and char \0 */
      sprintf(ptr, "%c^%d",  term->var, term->exponent);
    }
  }
  else if (term->coefficient == -1)
  {
    if (term->exponent == 1)
    {
      ptr = malloc(3);
      ptr[0] = '-';
      ptr[1] = term->var;
      ptr[2] = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
      ptr = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", term->exponent) + 4); /* +4 for - and var and ^ and char \0 */
      sprintf(ptr, "-%c^%d",  term->var, term->exponent);
    }
  }
  else if (term->exponent == 1)
  {
    ptr = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", term->coefficient) + 2); /* +2 for var and char \0 */
    sprintf(ptr, "%d%c", term->coefficient, term->var);
  }
  else
  {
    ptr = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d%d", term->exponent, term->coefficient) + 3); /* +3 for var and ^ and char \0 */
    sprintf(ptr, "%d%c^%d", term->coefficient, term->var, term->exponent);
  }

  return ptr;
}

int main()
{
  term_t test[] = { 
    {0, 1, 'x'},
    {1, 0, 'x'},
    {1, 1, 'x'},
    {1, -1, 'x'},
    {1, 2, 'x'},
    {2, 1, 'x'},
    {2, -1, 'x'},
    {2, 3, 'x'}
  };

  for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(test)/sizeof(term_t); ++i) {
    char * s = term_to_string(&test[i]);

    printf("test {exp=%d, coef=%d, var='%c'} : %s\n", 
           test[i].exponent, test[i].coefficient, test[i].var, s);
    free(s);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra e.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
test {exp=0, coef=1, var='x'} : 1
test {exp=1, coef=0, var='x'} : 0
test {exp=1, coef=1, var='x'} : x
test {exp=1, coef=-1, var='x'} : -x
test {exp=1, coef=2, var='x'} : 2x
test {exp=2, coef=1, var='x'} : x^2
test {exp=2, coef=-1, var='x'} : -x^2
test {exp=2, coef=3, var='x'} : 3x^2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==4285== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4285== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4285== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4285== Command: ./a.out
==4285== 
test {exp=0, coef=1, var='x'} : 1
test {exp=1, coef=0, var='x'} : 0
test {exp=1, coef=1, var='x'} : x
test {exp=1, coef=-1, var='x'} : -x
test {exp=1, coef=2, var='x'} : 2x
test {exp=2, coef=1, var='x'} : x^2
test {exp=2, coef=-1, var='x'} : -x^2
test {exp=2, coef=3, var='x'} : 3x^2
==4285== 
==4285== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4285==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4285==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 1,050 bytes allocated
==4285== 
==4285== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4285== 
==4285== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4285== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```